# Searching my custom BDC model errors

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope, bdc-model, custom-bdc

I wrote a custom BDC model, and it works. I can create a list, look at the items, look at a single item, create external data columns in other lists, etc.

Now I created a content source to index this. When I run a full crawl it errors

> Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object. )

My ULS logs have

```
11/23/2011 13:25:57.60      w3wp.exe (0x0CF4)                            0x23C0     SharePoint Server Search           Admin Audit                        96     Information     A full crawl was started on 'Yellow Pages' by domain\dave.lozzi.     026ffd1d-3d5f-4d20-a976-6f23203bd5e9
11/23/2011 13:26:04.14      w3wp.exe (0x1558)                            0x0A98     Business Connectivity Services     Business Data                      9f4d     Unexpected     'BDC' BdcServiceApplication logging server side MetadataObjectNotFoundException before marshalling and rethrowing on client side: IEntity could not be found by Entity Namespace = Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel, Name = FlatFileEntity Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.EntityAccessor.GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace(String namespace, String name, Guid partitionId, DbSessionWrapper dbSessionWrapper)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplication.<>c__DisplayClassa7.<Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.IBdcServiceApplication.GetEntityWithNameAndNamespace>b__a6()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.BdcServiceApplication.Execute[T](String operationName, UInt32 maxRunningTime, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation)...     8cf8f71c-4df6-49b4-b432-72359bd955e4
11/23/2011 13:26:04.14*     w3wp.exe (0x1558)                            0x0A98     Business Connectivity Services     Business Data                      9f4d     Unexpected     ...  ------------------------      8cf8f71c-4df6-49b4-b432-72359bd955e4
11/23/2011 13:26:04.42      w3wp.exe (0x0DE8)                            0x1474     SharePoint Foundation              General                            bqk1     High         External List: Lookup of entity namespace 'Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel', name 'FlatFileEntity' failed. Exception: IEntity could not be found by Entity Namespace = Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel, Name = FlatFileEntity Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Static.DataAccess.EntityMaterializer.GetEntityByNameAndNamespace(String namespace, String name)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.MetadataModel.DatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog.GetEntity(String namespace, String name)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.InitializeByEntityNameAndNamespace(SPWeb webContext)      a1e90a47-f50f-4ad3-9c58-37e653773737
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dvt6     High         SetSTSErrorInfo ErrorMessage = Error from SharePoint site: Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel', Name = 'FlatFileEntity'. hr = 80131600  [sts3util.cxx:5120]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dvu0     High         STS3::StoreCachedError: Object initialization failed.  Message:  "Error from SharePoint site: Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel', Name = 'FlatFileEntity'." HR: 80131600  [sts3util.cxx:5214]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dvr6     High         STS3::COWSList::Initialize: List Id {091787dd-7466-4669-9334-96f20204dd75} Return error to caller, hr=80131600 errorMessage Error from SharePoint site: Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel', Name = 'FlatFileEntity'.  [sts3util.cxx:4350]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dv6a     High         CSTS3Accessor::InitURLType: Return error to caller, hr=80131600                 [sts3acc.cxx:1995]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dv3t     High         CSTS3Accessor::InitURLType fails, Url sts4://watspd01:81/siteurl=/siteid={ea53d092-1451-4007-9d63-784ca431f3ef}/weburl=/webid={a3465bf2-e7f3-49f4-837d-d9a604ca49e6}/listid={091787dd-7466-4669-9334-96f20204dd75}, hr=80131600  [sts3acc.cxx:259]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dvb1     High         CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url sts4://watspd01:81/siteurl=/siteid={ea53d092-1451-4007-9d63-784ca431f3ef}/weburl=/webid={a3465bf2-e7f3-49f4-837d-d9a604ca49e6}/listid={091787dd-7466-4669-9334-96f20204dd75}, hr=80131600  [sts3handler.cxx:312]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           PHSts                              dvb2     High         CSTS3Handler::CreateAccessorExD: Return error to caller, hr=80131600            [sts3handler.cxx:330]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      mssdmn.exe (0x1BC0)                          0x2368     SharePoint Server Search           FilterDaemon                       e4ye     High         FLTRDMN: Errorinfo is "Error from SharePoint site: Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'Mine.BDC.YellowPagesModel', Name = 'FlatFileEntity'."  [fltrsink.cxx:553]  d:\office\source\search\native\mssdmn\fltrsink.cxx    
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02      w3wp.exe (0x0DE8)                            0x18EC     SharePoint Foundation              General                            avfx     High         SOAP exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Entity (External Content Type) cannot be found with Namespace = 'http://watspd01:81', Name = 'New external content type'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.get_Entity()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFieldCollectionFromEntity()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.ScoutEntityFieldCollectionForViableSPFields(SPFieldCollection fldcollParent, IFieldCollection& fldcoll, Int32[]& rgifldViableSPFields, Int32& cfldViableSPFields, AssociationManager& assocmgr)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureFieldsFromEntity()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.Undirty()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteDataImpl.GetListXml(XmlTex...     fdf78ac6-d2dd-423e-8bed-d319d564a344
11/23/2011 13:26:05.02*     w3wp.exe (0x0DE8)                            0x18EC     SharePoint Foundation              General                            avfx     High         ...tWriter w, SPWeb spWeb, SPList spList, Boolean ignoreSecurityIfInherit, Int32 schemaVersion)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteDataImpl.GetContent(ObjectType objectType, String objectId, String folderUrl, String itemId, Boolean retrieveChildItems, Boolean securityOnly, String& lastItemIdOnPage)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SiteData.GetContent(ObjectType objectType, String objectId, String folderUrl, String itemId, Boolean retrieveChildItems, Boolean securityOnly, String& lastItemIdOnPage)     fdf78ac6-d2dd-423e-8bed-d319d564a344
```

And ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. I was using SPContext in the ReadList method. SPContext doesn't exist for the timer job services running. Applied a work around and it runs great!